# Trying to find a dataframe column name value in another df, bring it back to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe from a crosstab called df2:

```
paidmonth                                                                     
201508      183323.0        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
201509      553608.0   145609.0        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
201510      443364.0   704912.0   218593.0        NaN        NaN        NaN   
...
```

I have another dataframe that looks like this called df5:

```
 effdate  insureds
0   201508     40681
1   201509     40989
2   201510     38734
...
```

I want to find for each column in df2, the df5(insureds) value and place it in the bottom row of df2.  So for column 201508, I need 40681 in the last row of df2, in the 201508 column.

I tried to loop through like this:

```py
for col in df2.columns:
    rval=df5.loc[df5['effdate']==col].index[0]
    insval=df5.loc[rval,:].values[1]
```

but keep getting an out of bonds error

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood well a merge will do the trick.
Have a look through the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

```py
pd.merge(df2, df5, how='left', left_on='paidmonth', right_on = 'effdate')
```

From what I can see you need either a left join or an inner join (change `how='inner'`).
I hope this helps.